# Error : Request Time Out in Rest API response in iOS 10 Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rest, request

I have updated my XCode from Xcode 7.3 to XCode 8 before 2 days.

When running in XCode 8 with iOS 10 Simulator, The rest Apis gives me error :

> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000250cb0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

But When same Project I run in My iPhone Xcode 8 with iOS 9.3 , The Rest Api response work perfect.

1. My First Project I am using NSUrlConnection to call API
2. My Second Project I am using AFNetworking to call API

Please help If anyone having same issue I have spend 2 days on it.

Thanks Advance

Comment: Did you find any solution to this.